# How to show text outside input ONFOCUS?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="search.php" class='search' method='GET'>
<input 
    type="text/submit"
    class="home_search_area"
    value="Search"
    name="search" 
    onblur="if(value=='') value = 'Search'" 
    onfocus="if(value=='Search') value = ''"
 /></form>
```

Now my form hides word "Search" on focus. I want to show text "Press enter to start searching" outside textarea onfocus. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an element under the input field:

```
<div id="tips"></div>
```

add to the onfocus event:

```
onfocus="if(value=='Search') value = ''; document.getElementById('tips').innerHTML = 'Press enter...'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a Second DIV or SPAN Element near the input element and give it an ID and show your text in that

```
<script>
function test(){
if(this.value=='Search'){
this.value = '';
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Press enter to start searching";
}

}
</script>
<form action="search.php" class='search' method='GET'>
<input 
    type="text/submit"
    class="home_search_area"
    value="Search"
    name="search" 
    onblur="if(value=='') value = 'Search'" 
    onfocus="test(this);"
 />
<div id=show></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just put an empty div to the side, and have `$("#hintdiv").innerHTML = 'Press enter to start searching'` in the onfocus

Answer (score 0):

Use ids, div like answer above and function like

```
function MyOnFocusFunc() {
    document.getElementById(yourinputid).value = '';
    document.getElemenbById('hintdiv').innerHTML = 'Press enter to start searching';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="showtext"></span>
<form action="search.php" class='search' method='GET'>
<input 
type="text/submit"
class="home_search_area"
value="Search"
name="search"  
onfocus="document.getElementById('showtext').innerHTML = 'Press enter  to start searching'"
/></form>
```

Comment: looks like you forgot about his original logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<form action="search.php" class='search' method='GET'>
<input 
    type="text/submit"
    class="home_search_area"
    value="Search"
    name="search" 
    onblur="if(value=='') value = 'Search'" 
    onfocus="if(value=='Search') value = ''"
    id="myInput"
 />
<div id="ShowThis" style="display:none;">Press enter to start searching</div>
</form>
```

Then Jquery

```
$('#myInput').focus( function() {
    $('#ShowThis').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't see the tags. I think the OP is looking for A Javascript, not Jquery answer.